# Nestedscrollview doesn't scroll child recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm having this problem where I have a recyclerview inside a nestedscrollview, but the nestedscrollview doesn't scroll the recyclerview.

Here is a gif of the situation: [image: gif of the recyclerview]

The recyclerview clearly has more children, but nestedscrollview won't scroll to them.

Heres the the framents layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bright_red"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/login_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="@string/fragment_future_title"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="70dp"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Add this to your recycler view xml android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

Comment: @udit7395 Yeah, I had programmatically disabled it before and this fixed it. It also caused/exposed a different problem where the fling action doesn't work all the time. It just stops mid fling.

But post this as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: 2 things.First of all your card's look amazing if possible please share the xml(just the cards). Second about the fling you can give this a try .Have you tried using ScrollView ? So If you plan to use Scrollview then in your code just programaticlly disable recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); and see if the output you get is as desired

Comment: Nestedscrollview is required for the collapsing toolbarlayout to work. and setting nestedscrolling=false was the original state that caused the scrolling not to work. 
You can check the code at https://github.com/KonstaL/Bullet-your-life. 
The relevant layout-code can be found in daycard.xml

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently  I was wrong and nestedscrollview isn't required for collapsingtoolbarlayout to work properly. Removing the nestedscrollview fixed the fling problem. Thanks udit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your recycler view xml

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Or the same can be done programatically

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```